# Double/ordinal number expression

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

I would like to know the pronunciation for these following expressions:

i) (1, 2日), (6, 7日), (7, 8日), (8, 9日), (8, 10日), (18~20日)

ii) 第2日, 第3日, 第4日, 第5日, 第6日, 第7日, 第8日, 第9日, 第10日, 第20日

Comment: I guess it would help if you explained what you meant by (1, 2日) and  (18~20日)

Comment: "1, 2日" means "1日 and 2日", and "18~20日" means "18日 to 20日".

Comment: Do you mean calendar date or duration (i.e. one or two days)?

Comment: What I mean is duration and ordinal day.